# Can't access class variable in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, inheritance

I have a class like so:

Railsapp/lib/five9_providers/record_provider.rb:

```
class Five9Providers::RecordProvider < Five9Providers::BaseProvider

  def add_record_to_list
    variable = 'test'
  end

end
```

Then, in a controller I have this:

Railsapp/app/controllers/five9_controller.rb:

```
class Five9Controller < ApplicationController

    def import
      record_provider = Five9Providers::RecordProvider.new()
      record_provider.add_record_to_list
      puts Five9Providers::RecordProvider::variable
    end

end
```

However, calling my controller method `import` just returns:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method 'variable' for Five9Providers::RecordProvider:Class)
```

How can I access `variable` from the `recover_provider.rb` class in my `five9_controller.rb` class?

EDIT:

Even when using `@@variable` in both my `record_provider` and my `five9_controller`, I still can't access that variable. I am calling it like so: `puts @@variable`.

Comment: This is *extremely* basic Ruby stuff. I would try at least learning Ruby before building a self-guided Rails app.

Comment: Sanity check: "recover_provider.rb" and "five9_controller.rb" are not classes. They're files, which happen to contain class definitions. Be careful how you refer to things as using the wrong terms will really obstruct your ability to be understood by others.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan. Soaking up as much knowledge as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, you cannot. `variable` is local to the instance method and can't be accessed by any Ruby expression from outside the method.

On a related point, the term "class variable" is typically used to refer to variables of the form `@@variable`.

**Update**: In response to your "Edit" statement, if you change `variable` to `@@variable` in your class, then there are techniques available to access that variable from outside the class, but a naked reference to `@@variable` isn't one of them. Carefully read the answers to [the question you cited in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590723/what-is-the-proper-way-to-access-class-variables-in-ruby-1-9) for more information.

Comment: Could you suggest an alternative? I was following the structure listed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590723/what-is-the-proper-way-to-access-class-variables-in-ruby-1-9

What can I do to access `variable`?

Comment: @Luigi, you need to study how Ruby handles variable conventions and scope. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope. A class variable would start with `@@`. An instance variable would start with `@`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @mbratch. What is this talk about using constants instead of class variables though? Class variables seem to cause more harm than good. I will definitely check the link and continue my studying though, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Luigi, whether a class variable causes harm or not depends upon how well you design the code. They are available if and when needed and when used properly. :) You do need to determine if you need an instance variable versus a class variable (hard to tell with your brief example). Constants can be defined as well and accessed from the class. A discussion of the pros and cons of using class versus instance versus private variables and pros/cons of how Ruby handles them is way outside the scope of your originally posted question.

Comment: @mbratch Agreed on all fronts, I obviously have a lot to learn. I edited my original post to contain more information.

Comment: As I said in my answer, there is _nothing_ you can do to access variable as it's currently defined. The SO question you reference discusses a variety of techniques for accessing variables defined within a class, but what you've done here doesn't match any of the techniques described.

Comment: @Luigi, in your case, the way you access it, you need a class variable (`@@variable`). But you might want to consider rather adding setter/getter methods instead. The code sample you are showing may not be good practice depending upon the "big picture" of what it is you are trying to achieve

Comment: See updated answer for information on the addendum you included in your latest concerning accessing `@@variable`

Comment: Thanks fellas - I looked elsewhere before posting this and was actually just missing the `cattr_accessor` method, as mentioned in the SO reference in the above answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So we can't access by doing classname::@@variable_name ?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to set and get the value using methods. Below is a sample code

```
class Planet
  @@planets_count = 0

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @@planets_count += 1
  end

  def self.planets_count
    @@planets_count
  end  

  def self.add_planet
    @@planets_count += 1
  end

  def add_planet_from_obj
    @@planets_count += 1
  end
end


Planet.new("uranus")
Plant.add_planet
obj = Planet.new("earth")
obj.add_planet_from_obj
```