# Saving instance list in class variable

Tags: ruby

I want to store newly created `Person` instance inside the class variable `objects`, but not sure how to reference the current instance from the constructor.

```
class Person
  @@objects = {}

  def initialize(key)
    @@objects[key] = something
  end
```

Ideally, the result is to be able to access the dictionary of `Person` objects through `Person.objects`

Comment: `self` would refer to the current instance

Comment: Be aware of the consequences of using class variables in Ruby. There's usually a better way to achieve what you're trying to do without class variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, in constructor function, `self` will refer to the current instance.

```
class Person
  @@objects = {}

  def initialize(key)
    @@objects[key] = self
    puts self # it will print the id of the current instance
  end
end
```

Same way, if you write `self` in a class method, it will refer to the the class.

But from your question, you seem to be doing something like `Person.objects`, and it won't work, and will output the following line:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `objects' for Person:Class
```

So, you need to write a *class* method for it to let the outside world access `objects`.

```
def self.objects
  @@objects
end
```

Well, there are other ways as well to access the class variables, please have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590723/what-is-the-proper-way-to-access-class-variables-in-ruby-1-9).